# Wait 3 seconds to see if a variable is changed then fire something

Tags: javascript, variables, time, debouncing

Here is a piece of JavaScript Code to do Speech Recognition using Web Speech API. This piece of code is responsible for restarting Speech Recognition after user finished speaking. Now I want to modify this code to give users **3-second chances** to speak a different sentence when they saw speechResult variable on their screen.

Here is the scenario:

1) User speaks, Then Voice Recognition puts their speech as text in "speechResult" variable and displays it on their screens.

2) We wait 3 seconds to give the user another chance if he/she wants to speak a different sentence.

3) After 3 seconds without any change in "speechResult", we fire some if statements to assign "isCorrect" variable with true or false values...

```
 recognition.onend = function(event) {
      //Fired when the speech recognition service has disconnected.

recognition.start();

     // Some code to do: If "speechResult" variable changes, wait for 3 
      seconds then fire if statement below.//

 const debounce = (func, delay) => { 
let debounceTimer 
return function() { 
    const context = this
    const args = arguments 
        clearTimeout(debounceTimer) 
            debounceTimer 
        = setTimeout(() => func.apply(context, args), delay) 
} 
}  

debounce function() { 


if (speechResult == "who are you") {
    isCorrect= true;

} else {
    isCorrect= false;
}
} }, 3000);
```

Comment: This is generally called debouncing. Instead of waiting for the variable to change, delay taking action on the event until the event doesn't happen for 3 seconds. Each time the event occurs, clear previous timeouts and start a new one.

Comment: See [posts countaining 'debounce'](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+debounce)

Comment: I'm trying debouncing that without success, any Idea how to do debouncing here ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setTimeout` like this:

```js
recognition.onend = function(event) {
  //Fired when the speech recognition service has disconnected.
  recognition.start();

  setTimeout(processResult, 3000);
}

function processResult(speechResult) {
  if (speechResult == "who are you") {
    isCorrect= true;
  } else {
    isCorrect= false;
  }
}
```

`setTimeout` returns a number you can use with `clearTimeout` if you receive a condition that should cancel it.  Or you could use a debounce function.

Comment: Thank you for your immediate response, this way the user only has a one-time chance ( 3 seconds ) to try his best. I want that setTimeout work every time he speaks (every time speechResult changes) ...

Comment: Clear all setTimeout at the beginning of processResult and call it again at the end of processResult (if condition isCorrect is false maybe?)